# Write BMP image

Tags: c, image, image-processing

I'm currently learning C and I started to write a BMP image reader and writer, to make some operations with basic images.

I'm reading the BMP image and saving it into a struct, then just write a copy to ensure that the flow is working, but, when I write the image I get the following result

[image: BMP write result]

Where the left one is the original and the right one the copy, I don't know if I'm not saving enough memory or if I'm not writing in the right way the data.

I have the header file and the implementation, where I wrote two functions `readImage` and `writeImage`, both receive the filename and the Image struct described in the header file.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef uint16_t ImageType;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t size;
    uint16_t additionalFeature;
    uint16_t copy;
    uint32_t offset;

} ImageHeader;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t headerSize;
    int width;
    int height;
    uint16_t colorSpaces;
    uint16_t bitsPerPixel;
    uint32_t compression;
    uint32_t size;
    int verticalResolution;
    int horizontalResolution;
    uint32_t totalColors;
    uint32_t importantColors;
} ImageMetadata;

typedef struct {
    int red; 
    int green; 
    int blue;
    int reserved;
} ImageColors;

typedef unsigned char *ImagePixels;

typedef struct {
    ImageType type;
    ImageHeader header;
    ImageMetadata metadata;
    ImagePixels pixels;
} Image;

ImageType BMP_IMAGE_TYPE = 0x4D42;

void readImage(char *filename, Image *image);
void writeImage(char *filename, Image *image);
void fragmentImage(Image *image);
```

```c
#include "bmp.h"

void readImage(char *filename, Image *image)
{
    FILE *imageFile = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!imageFile)
    {
        perror("ReadImageFileException");
        fclose(imageFile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fread(&(image->type), sizeof(ImageType), 1, imageFile);
    if (image->type != BMP_IMAGE_TYPE)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%hu", image->type);
        perror("ReadImageTypeException");
        fclose(imageFile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fread(&(image->header), sizeof(ImageHeader), 1, imageFile);
    fread(&(image->metadata), sizeof(ImageMetadata), 1, imageFile);

    image->pixels = (unsigned char *)malloc(image->metadata.width * image->metadata.height);
    if (!image->pixels)
    {
        perror("ReadImagePixelsException");
        fclose(imageFile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fseek(imageFile, image->header.offset, SEEK_SET);
    fread(image->pixels, sizeof(char) * image->metadata.width * image->metadata.height, 1, imageFile);

    fclose(imageFile);
}

void writeImage(char *filename, Image *image)
{
    FILE *imageFile = fopen(filename, "w+");
    if (!imageFile)
    {
        perror("WriteImageFileException");
        fclose(imageFile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int typeWritten = fwrite(&(image->type), sizeof(image->type), 1, imageFile);
    if (typeWritten == 0)
    {
        perror("WriteImageTypeException");
        fclose(imageFile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int headerWritten = fwrite(&(image->header), sizeof(image->header), 1, imageFile);
    if (headerWritten == 0)
    {
        perror("WriteImageHeaderException");
        fclose(imageFile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int metadataWritten = fwrite(&(image->metadata), sizeof(image->metadata), 1, imageFile);
    if (metadataWritten == 0)
    {
        perror("WriteImageMetadataException");
        fclose(imageFile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fseek(imageFile, image->header.offset, SEEK_SET);
    int pixelsWritten = fwrite(image->pixels, sizeof(char) * image->metadata.width * image->metadata.height, 1, imageFile);
    if (pixelsWritten == 0)
    {
        perror("WriteImagePixelsException");
        fclose(imageFile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fclose(imageFile);
}
```

In the main file, I declare the image data structure and pass it to both functions

```c
#include "bmp.c"

int main() {
    Image image;
    readImage("image.bmp", &image);
    writeImage("image-copy.bmp", &image);
    return 0;
}
```

¿Someone could help to identify what I'm doing wrong? I already try to allocate more memory or calculate the size of the data structure that saves the pixels with the header that saves the image size, but it didn't work.

Comment: Are there 3 values per pixel?

Comment: No, all the image data/pixels are being saved in a char pointer.

Comment: It seems you've written exactly 1/3 of the image? Probably some sizing issue, where you need to multiply by 3? (AKA its a color image rather than grayscale)

Comment: @Mikhail - good catch. 288 pixels high, 96 present. It possibly worth mentioning here that the image (though this one doesn't) might be padded at the end of each scan-line too. That's a bit of a rude surprise when one first encounters it.

Comment: @enhzflep: "That's a bit of a rude surprise when one first encounters it": I am fully with you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fread(image->pixels, sizeof(char) * image->metadata.width * image->metadata.height, 1, imageFile);
```

```
fwrite(image->pixels, sizeof(char) * image->metadata.width * image->metadata.height, 1, imageFile);
```

Maybe your original bmp file has each pixel size more than 8 bit? Image seems to only have one third part of original image so original image might have 24bit format.

How about trying `3 * sizeof(char)`?

Comment: Try printing bitsPerPixel in ImageMetadata. It might prove the point.

Comment: Yes, now I multiply by the number of bytes needed, base on the BPP, but the other images, still working weird. A black and white image and a grayscale image, the only that works fine is the color one. should I open other question?

Comment: @DanielAlessandroAguilar How wierd does it behave? If the problem is related to bits per pixel, you can check ```image->metadata->bitsPerPixel```. The value is 24 if bmp file is 24bit format, 8 if 8, etc. Then you can adjust size parameter of fwrite function accordingly. If the problem is different please specify it.

Answer (score 0):

An image in the 24 bpp format takes three bytes per pixel. And if necessary the rows are padded with dummy bytes to the next size that is a multiple of four.